# Is there a way to hide freestyle outlines on Mask objects

Tags: freestyle, outliner

Is there a way to hide freestyle outlines on Mask objects. No matter what I have tried it the outline is always there.[image]

Answer (score 1):

Blender's FreeStyle functionality is a rendering engine, which means that it is not object-based. You can only turn it off for the whole scene.

Take a look at this picture from the Blender Manual

[image]

The first box is your 3D scene with all its objects. Everything else in the process happens after the objects, their positions and materials are processed.

Answer (score 1):

Just group all your objects to have lines then **restrict the FreeStyle render to that group**.

[image]

Answer (score -3):

Looks like you are using BI. I use Freestyle with Cycles. Also I have not much experiences with using masks in general.

That being said, you could try using different render layers (but maybe not usable   because of the mask) and fix in compositing.
Or you could try putting the object in its own group and limit the freestyle lines to that group.